# Строение андроид приложения с авторизацией

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, single-activity

Вопрос в том, как реализовать вход в приложение с авторизацией. Ведь если пользователь залогинен - то должен открываться основной экран, а если нет - то должно открываться окно авторизации. Сначала была идея создать пустую активити с Theme.NoDisplay, в ней проверять залогинен ли и в зависимости от этого перекидывать на разные экраны. Но потом выяснилось, что приложение должно быть SingleActivity. Является ли первое решение правильным, если не учитывать, что приложение долнжо быть SingleActivity и как правильно реализовать этот момент, если приложение SingleActivity?

Comment: Используй Splashscreen

Answer (score 0):

вот здесь пример c MVVM архитектурой на Java на английском
https://learntodroid.com/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-in-an-android-app-using-mvvm/